# Не устанавливается системная переменная path для mysql?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, mysql

Хочу себе прописать переменную `path` для `mysql`, все как [здесь][1] написано делаю:![изображение][2]увы после ввода каких-либо команд `mysql` получаю:    C:>mysql    "mysql" не является внутренней или внешней    командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.  [1]: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-installation-windows-path.html  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SdLJu.png

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы очень невнимательно прочитали инструкцию по вашей же ссылке. Нужно не *переименовывать* переменную Path в mysql. А *добавить к ней в конец* (нижнее поле ввода на вашей картинке) строку "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\bin" или что там у вас. Причём добавить не вплотную, а через точку с запятой. Например, было:

```
%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem
```

Станет:

```
%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\bin
```

При этом имя переменной как было Path, так им и должно остаться.